# Can Sunspot/Solr work with different RequestHandlers for different Rails classes?

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have one Rails app with two very different classes that are being indexed in Solr (using Sunspot). One is users and the other is a product catalog. There are specific RequestHandlers that I'd like to use for just the product catalog.

Do I set up two Solr instances with different config? If so, how do I point each class to the right instance?

Otherwise is there a way in Sunspot/Solr to tie a class or request to specific RequestHandlers?

Comment: http://outoftime.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20339/tickets/99-ability-to-change-request-handler - It seems it is supported.

Comment: Hi @Jayendra. I think that was the exact answer I was looking for!! You should post as an answer, not just a note.

Comment: sure .. added it as an answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sunspot does provide the ability to specify the handler, check [link](http://outoftime.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20339/tickets/99-ability-to-change-request-handler).